# How can I detect that a symlink is broken in Perl?

Tags: perl, symlink

I would like to remove a broken symlink in a directory using Perl.

In my mind I just had to list the file of a directory and test is this a symlink (`-l`) and if it returns false just unlink it.

But it appears that when using readir to list all files my broken symlinks are not recoganized as a file. Because my link is pointing to nothing I understand why.

All the file in `$myDir` are symlinks, either valid or broken.
When I display @files I only get a list of valid symlink.

```
opendir DIR, $myDir;
my @files = grep(/$regexp/,readdir(DIR));
closedir DIR;
print "filenames : @files\n";
```

Comment: What do you mean "are not recoganized as a file"?  by what?  show your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two main relevant system calls, [`stat()` and `lstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html).  The `lstat()` call will tell you that it is a symlink (but on other files, behaves the same as `stat()`).  This allows you to determine that the name is a symlink.  The `stat()` system call follows a symlink to its end, and tells you about the file (or directory) at the end of the link.  If the `stat()` call fails on the symlink, then the symlink is broken or you're trying to access a directory or file where you have no permission.

The Perl [file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) operators include `-l` to detect whether a name is a symlink.  You can use the Perl functions [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) and [`lstat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html) explicitly.  Between these, you should be able to sort out whether a symlink is broken or not - but you should probably plan to write a function to do the job.

You probably don't need to use the [`readlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink.html) Perl function.  Beware the underlying system [`readlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) call; it does not return a null-terminated string!

It is interesting that neither Perl nor its POSIX module supports the [`realpath()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) function.  However, the [PathTools](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cwd) module does support it.  If `realpath` fails, on a symlink, the symlink is non-functional (aka broken).

Answer (score 8):

Combining `lstat` with `stat`:

```
say "dangling link at $fn" if (lstat $fn and not stat $fn);
```

**update**: it works for me...

```
salva@topo:~/t/dl$ perl -E 'opendir $dh, "."; say $_ for grep { !stat $_ and lstat $_ } readdir $dh'
foo
salva@topo:~/t/dl$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 salva salva  0 2011-07-05 12:34 f
lrwxrwxrwx 1 salva salva 11 2011-07-05 12:00 fii -> /etc/shadow
lrwxrwxrwx 1 salva salva 12 2011-07-05 11:59 foo -> /etc/hjdkshf
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code I've used to remove broken links:

```
chdir $dir        or die;
opendir(DIR, '.') or die;

foreach my $link (readdir DIR) {
  next unless -l $link and not -e readlink($link);

  print "Removing broken link $link\n";
  unlink $link;
}

closedir DIR;
```

Note that it's important that the directory containing the links is the current directory.  `readdir` returns only filenames, and the links might be relative.

Comment: +1: Good point about relativity of names.  You could add the value from `readdir` to the name (relative or absolute) of the directory and work from that: `next unless -l "$dir/$link" and not -e "$dir/$link"`.  I omitted the `readlink` in that rewrite; I think that is OK since the O/S reads the link for you.

Answer (score 3):

Check for broken symlinks (checking only the top level if there are symlinks to symlinks):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
opendir my $dirh, '.';
while (my $file = readdir $dirh) {
    if ( -l $file ) {
        my $target = readlink $file;
        if ( ! -e $target && ! -l $target ) {
            print "$file -> $target broken\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `readlink()` and `stat()` the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in Perl glob function ?
For examples:

```
 @files = <*>;
 foreach $file (@files) {
   print $file . "\n";
 }
```

For a specific `$dir`:

```
 @files = <$dir*>;
 foreach $file (@files) {
   print $file . "\n";
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't work if `$dir` contains characters that are special in `glob`, such as spaces or `*` or `?`.

Answer (score 0):

A broken symlink is a link (`-l`) that does not exists (`!-e`)

```
perl -e 'print "broken: $_\n" for grep { -l and ! -e } glob("*");'
```